# wordpress function esc_url not working in https

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

this code is working in http

```
<section id="nicdark_singlepage_parallax" class="nicdark_section nicdark_imgparallax" style="background:url(<?php echo esc_url(  $redux_demo['metabox_pages_header_img']['url'] ); ?>) 50% 0 fixed; background-size:cover;">
```

but active https is not working

Comment: Please include your HTML source as the result of above code so we can help. Maybe your image link still HTTP so the browser prevent to load them on HTTPS site.

Comment: Why does not anyone help me

Comment: @AnhTuan 

<section id="nicdark_singlepage_parallax" class="nicdark_section nicdark_imgparallax" style="background:url() 50% 0 fixed; background-size:cover;">